# collect number of zeros in substring

Tags: java

I can't get the following program working properly. When it encounters an `N` in the string `dursend`, it uses `.split`. Then it collects a `1` for each single `N`, and a `2` for an N followed by one `Q`, and so on. Then a number of `0`'s must be collected which equals the number of `Q`'s. The right output should be:
`011111120111111201111111111111111` in which the first `0` should be ignored. The output I get is: `01111112011111201111111111111110`,
so it seems that after printing the `0` after the first `2` the program is going wrong: it gives 5 times `1` instead of 6 times `1`.

```java
public class T3 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String durs = "NNNNNNNQNNNNNNNQNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN";
    System.out.println(durs);
    int d = countOccurrencesDurations(durs, 'N');
    int d1 = countOccurrencesDurations(durs, 'Q');
    int m = 32;
    int[] cdn = new int[m];
    int d2;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(durs);
    String dursend = sb.append("W").toString();
    String[] a = new String[d];
    a = dursend.split("N");
    // int alen = a.length + d1 - 1;
    // System.out.println("a: " + alen);
    int i = 1;
    while (i < a.length) {
      // System.out.println("N" + a[i]);
      d2 = countOccurrencesDurations(a[i], 'Q');
      // System.out.println(d2);
      int d3 = d2 + 1;
      cdn[i] += d3;
      for (int j = 0; j < d2; j++) {
        i++;
        cdn[i] += 0;
      }
      i++;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
      System.out.print(cdn[k]);
    }
  }

  public static int countOccurrencesDurations(String haystack, char needle)
  {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < haystack.length(); i++) {
      if (haystack.charAt(i) == needle) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need a working solution or want to find the bug in your own program?

Comment: It would be great if you have a solution without changing my code too much. But I also accept other solutions which I can use directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this if you need a working solution. *I updated my solution according to your comment.*

```
public class Main {

    private static String result;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String durs = "NNNNNNQQNNNNNNNQNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN";

        result = "";

        int qCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < durs.length(); i++){
            if (durs.charAt(i) == 'N'){
                // Process accumulated Q's from before
                if (qCount > 0){
                    processQ(qCount);
                    qCount = 0;
                }

                // Do nothing if there is a Q next to us
                if ((i != durs.length() - 1) && durs.charAt(i + 1) == 'Q'){
                    continue;
                }

                result += "1";


            }else{
                qCount++;
            }
        }

        if (qCount > 0){
            processQ(qCount);
        }


        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static void processQ(int qCount) {
        if (qCount > 0){
            result += (qCount + 1);
            for(int j = 0; j < qCount; j++){
                result += "0";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I believe this one works fine.

Comment: That is not an answer to my question. Let me give another string: NNNNNNQQNNNNNNNQNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN This should output:
01111130011111120111111111111111 But it outputs:
011111300111120111111111111111 So the number of Q's has to be counted and added by 1. Then the number of 0's has to be printed which is 2 in this case.

Comment: You mean there can be `"30"` `"40"` ... etc?

Comment: The substring "NQQ" must give "300" and the substring "NQQQ" must give "4000".

Comment: You're welcome. You can also use `StringBuilder` for `result` in order to increase performance for longer inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simplified version (somewhat aligned to your implementation):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char last = 0;
for (char c : durs.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == 'Q' && last == 'N') {
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        sb.append("20");
    } else if (c == 'N') {
        sb.append("1");
    }
    last = c;
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```